# PL / SQL Trigger to format information with compilation errors

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, oracle11g

this is my very first question, I'm new here so I hope I'm asking well in the right topic... etc.
I'm trying with a trigger wich catch information from one table, compares some data from this table and if a condition is true then the trigger have to store the information changing some values. There are my  tables and the trigger. I need this trigger to store larger tables with a lot of columns and a lot more information but this is just a test, please help! :'(

```
create table datos_prueba(
nombre varchar2(10) primary key,
numero number(3),
mensaje varchar(30),
fecha date);

create table store_datos_prueba(
nombre varchar(20) primary key,
numero number(5),
mensaje varchar(30),
fecha date);
```

And this is the trigger, I worte it but it's wrong...

```
create or replace trigger tgr_trigger_prueba
    after insert on datos_prueba 
    for each row
declare
    cambio_numero number;
begin
    if :datos_prueba.numero <= 5 then
        insert into store_datos_prueba (nombre,numero,mensaje,fecha) values(:datos_prueba.nombre,666,:datos_prueba.mensaje,:datos_prueba.fecha);
    else
        insert into store_datos_prueba (nombre,numero,mensaje,fecha) values(:datos_prueba.nombre,777,:datos_prueba.mensaje,:datos_prueba.fecha);
    end if;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `old` or `new` to refer the *row* value. Not the table name.

```
    create or replace trigger tgr_trigger_prueba
        after insert on datos_prueba 
        for each row
    declare
        cambio_numero number;
    begin
        if :new.numero <= 5 then
            insert into store_datos_prueba (nombre,numero,mensaje,fecha) values(:new.nombre,666,:new.mensaje,:new.fecha);
        else
            insert into store_datos_prueba (nombre,numero,mensaje,fecha) values(:new.nombre,777,:new.mensaje,:new.fecha);
        end if;
    end;
    /
```

[More on Triggers](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg13trg.htm)

Comment: `:old` will return NULL for inserts. I think you mean `:new`.

Comment: @maheswaran-revisankar cool man! thank u so much, it perfectly work :)